# Пост на странице пользователя через VK API (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как опубликовать пост c картинкой из внешнего ресурса через ВК API (JS)?
Как правильно прописать параметр attachments что-бы прикрепилась картинка по ссылке?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опубликовать пост с внешним изображением — нельзя.

Изображение предварительно нужно загрузить на сервера ВКонтакте. Подробнее о загрузке изображений: [vk.com/dev/upload_files](https://vk.com/dev/upload_files?f=2.%20%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0%20%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B9%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%83)